# Loop Json Links Swift

Tags: json, swift, xcode, get-request, getresponse

I've got an array with two links where I want to get the value of `id`. The code works but the `device_id_array` varies between `[88.0, 89.0] and [89.0, 88.0]` and I don't know how to fix this. 
Thanks for your help.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    device_link_array = ["http://link1.com", "http://link2.com"]

    for link in device_link_array {
        let url = URL(string: link)


        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in
            if error != nil
            {
                print("Error")

            }else{

                if let content = data{
                    do{     

                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: []) as! [String:Any]

                        if let device_id = json["id"]{
                            device_id_array.append(device_id as! Double)
                        }
                        print(device_id_array)

                    }catch{}
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Json Link1 :
{
"id": 88
}

Json Link2 :
{
"id": 89
}

UPDATE:

```
    device_link_array = ["http://link1.com", "http://link2.com"]

    let group = DispatchGroup()
    for links in device_link_array {
        let url = URL(string: links)

        group.enter()
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in
            if error != nil
            {
                print("Error")
            }
            else{

                if let content = data{
                    do{

                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: []) as! [String:Any]
                        if let device_id = json["id"]{
                            device_id_array.append(device_id as! Double)

                        }
                        print(device_id_array)

                    }catch{}
                }
            }
            group.leave()
        }

        task.resume()

    }
}
```

Comment: `dataTask` works asynchronously therefore the order is not guaranteed. If you need an order sort the array. By the way: `GET` is the default request. You don't need an explicit request. Just pass the URL: `dataTask(with: url) ...` And as you know the JSON is a dictionary why do cast it to unspecified `AnyObject`? Help the compiler and cast it to `[String:Any]`. And this is not javascript or PHP. Variable names are supposed to be *camelCased* rather than *snake_cased*

Comment: Thanks for the response and informations. Unfortunately ordering is an option. Is the a possibility to do it synchronously?

Comment: You can use [`DispatchGroup`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup) to keep the order

Comment: I updated my question trying to implement DispatchGroup. But no success. Do do have another hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an array of `Device` object defined by:

```
class Device {
    var link: String
    var identifier: Double?

    init(link: String) {
        self.link = link
    }
}

let deviceArray: [Device] = [
        Device(link: "http://link1.com"),
        Device(link: "http://link2.com")]
```

Then you change you loop to:

```
for device in deviceArray {
     let link = device.link
     ... // URLSession stuff
                if let deviceId = json["id"]{
                        device.identifer = deviceId as! Double
                }
                print(deviceArray)
     ...
```

You will be able to access to your first identifer with:

```
if let firstIdentifier = deviceArray[0].identifier {
    print(firstIdentifier)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it possible to add links programmatically? I can't figure out how this construct works with i.e. deviceArray.append.

Comment: Of course you can add Device to the deviceArray:
`deviceArray.append(Device(link: "https://newlink"))`

Answer (score 0):

The only way to guarantee the order of the calls is to make the next call in the callback of the previous one. That will work for a couple of links but doesn't generalize well. If the number varies and remains relatively small you could make an ordered "links to call" list and work through that in each callback until it is empty.